# PHP equivalents of .hasNext() and .hasNextLine()?

Tags: php, parsing, input, eol

What are the PHP equivalents of `.hasNext()` and `.hasNextLine()` in Java? If there is none, how do I detect *EOL* and *EOF*? Purpose: Have a file of generic length, but every line has the same format:

```
string number number
```

The end product derived from this list is two new text files, one where the lines are ordered after the first number, one where the lines are ordered after the second number.

Comment: For which purpose? files? strings? There's http://www.php.net/feof for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjoy the [Filesystem Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php):

- Read lines with [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/fgets)
- Find file end with [`feof()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php)

Answer (score 0):

file.txt

```
a
b
c
```

php code

```
$arr = file('file.txt');

$iter = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr));
foreach ($iter as $value) {
    var_dump( $iter->hasNext() );
}
```

output:

```
bool(true) bool(true) bool(false)
```